# How to configure multiple datasources in Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to replace some projects to use Spring Data JDBC 
 instead of using `JdbcTemplate`.

Now, I'd like to use it for multiple `DataSource`s, how can I configure it in Spring Data JDBC?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources

Comment: It's an example of spring-data-jpa, but I'd like to do it in spring-data-jdbc too.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for working with two or more `DataSource`s. You'd have to manually redo what the `JdbcRepositoryFactoryBean` does.

Comment: would it be possible to make that constructor public? Or at least protected? I've hit the wall hard with this last week and I can't easily solve this. Don't want to over-shadow classes during class-loading etc.

Comment: Back-linking the issue for future reference: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-321